# Calling select() on a UDP socket gives an invalid argument error

Tags: c, sockets, select

I am calling select() on a UDP socket to see if there is data to be read. Every time the method returns -1 and errno is set to 22 (Invalid Argument). Here is part of my code:

```
fd_set sockets;
struct timeval alarm;
alarm.tv_sec = 0;
alarm.tv_usec = 1000;
FD_ZERO(&sockets);
FD_SET(udpSocket, &sockets);
maxfd = udpsocket + 1;
selected = select(maxfd, &sockets, NULL, NULL, &alarm);
printf("%d\n", selected);
```

"Selected" is always -1. I know that the socket is fine because at this point I have already successfully sent data over it.

Comment: Can you update the question with the way you initialize the socket and the alarm please?

Comment: I highly suggest you rename your `struct timeval alarm` to something else, there happens to be a function of the same name (ie. `alarm()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the reason for the error was that I was setting the microseconds property of the alarm to:

```
alarm.tv_usec = 2000000;
```

Which apparently is too high a value. Obviously, it was just easier to set the seconds property to 2:

```
alarm.tv_sec = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Accroding to the manual page for select, `EINVAL` means "nfds  is negative or the value contained within timeout is invalid", which suggests that `udpsocket` is `-2` or less.

One possible hint: you set `udpSocket` in the fd_set and then use `udpsocket` to calculate `maxfd`.  Having two variables that differ only in the case of a single character is easy to miss.